# How to schedule Amazon Athena Spark notebooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

Athena supports Apache Spark via PySpark now. In Athena platform, you can create pyspark notebook and write pyspark codes and run them. But how can we schedule a job to run the notebook at a specific time automatically?